# Closed form for $\sum_{k=0}^{m} {\binom {m}{k}} a^{k} (b+ck)^N$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

> Is there a closed form for the following?
>   $$\sum_{k=0}^{m}  {\binom {m}{k}} a^{k} (b+ck)^N$$
>
> how about a pretty limit for large $b$.

I have tried using the binomial expansion for the $(b+ck)^N$ to convert the above expression to double sum and then tried to simplify the double sum which was not successful. Any idea if I have find a closed form for it?

Comment: Do you mean ${m\choose k}$?

Comment: yes, thanks,  I corrected it now.

Answer (score 3):

Define
$$
f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{m} {\binom {m}{k}} x^{b+ck} = x^b (1+x^c)^m.
$$
Define the differential operator $D(g(x)) = xg'(x)$, so that $D^2g(x)=D(D(g(x)) = xg'(x) + x^2g''(x)$, etc. Then
$$
D^N(f(x)) = \sum_{k=0}^{m} {\binom {m}{k}} D^N(x^{b+ck}) = \sum_{k=0}^{m} {\binom {m}{k}} (b+ck)^Nx^{b+ck},
$$
and so
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{m} {\binom {m}{k}} (b+ck)^Na^k = a^{-b/c} (D^Nf)(a^{1/c}).
$$
This will allow you to get a closed form for any particular value of $N$, just by applying $D^N$ to $x^b (1+x^c)^m$ and plugging in $x=a^{1/c}$.